# Splitting a string by several separators

Tags: c#

I have previously had to separate my strings using only

```
.Split(new char[]{" "},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Now however, the problem that the lecturer has given us, has to be solved with splitting the string by `( , ; : . ! ( ) " ' \ / [ ] space )`. How am I supposed to do that? I tried to put "" around each one, but it doesn't seem to work... Sorry for the noob question.

Tried:

```
var listchence = Console.ReadLine().Split(new char[] {",", ";" ":", ".", "!" "(", ")", """, "'", "\", "/", "[", "]", " "} .Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried and explain what you mean by doesnt work

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Okay, all your posts have a negative score.  Time to give in and read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: An example input string, followed by desired output would be nice. Do you understand that .Split takes a character array as a parameter, and that previously you were only supplying one value for the array, and that an array can contain more?

Comment: var listchence = Console.ReadLine()
                .Split(new char[] {",", ";" ":", ".", "!" "(", ")", """, "'", "\", "/", "[", "]", " "})
                .Select(int.Parse)
                .ToList();

Comment: @VictorErshov - please edit the question to include this. In addition what is the problem you get?

Comment: The code you've entered does not compile. You're creating a _char_ array but adding _strings_ to it.

Comment: Does any of the solutions below help you solve the problem. If so please consider upvoting helpful answers, and if any of the solutions solved your problem to accept that answer

Answer (score 2):

In C# there is a difference between using `""` and `''`. `""` is for specifying a `string` while a `'` is for specifying a char. You are initializing a `char[]` but populating it with strings.

Your code should be:

```
var listchence = Console.ReadLine()
                        .Split(new char[] {',', ';',':', '.', '!', '(', ')', '"', '\'', '\\', '/', '[', ']', ' '})
                        .Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

*Note that in the case of `'` and `\` you need to escape then adding another `\` in front of it*

Another option is to use the `Split` overload that receives a `string[]` but as all your separators are a single character better go with the `char[]` overload.

Answer (score 0):

There is an overload which accepts multiple delimiters. You'll need to put single quotes around each delimiter, because it accepts character arrays, not string arrays. Some of your delimiters need to be escaped, such as " and \ by adding a backslash in front of them.

Comment: Technically there is an overload of the `Split` method that takes `string[]`.

Answer (score -1):

```
.Split(new char[]{',',';',':','.','!','(',')', '\"', '\'','\\','/','[',' ]',' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!